# checking if two svg files are the same

Tags: java, svg

I need to come up with a way to detect if two SVG files are the same, using Java. I'm not too familiar with how SVG works, but I imagine that file->string and string comparison isn't the way to go - there's element ordering, some optional parameters may be omitted, that kind of stuff. How would I best go about it?

In case it matters - I need it for testing a SVG<->CGM converter a colleague is making. I was thinking of doing SVG->CGM->SVG roundtrip conversion and comparing the final result with the original SVG. That *is* a valid way to test such a converter, right?

Comment: How about writing both SVG images to canvas using drawImage and then comparing the two images pixel for pixel.

Comment: I suppose I could try that. Comparing two images pixel by pixel doesn't sound very quick, though. Are there any good ways to do the comparison based on the files' xml content? In which case it would be xml comparison.

Comment: That's how reftest-analyzer works and it's pretty much instant. It takes reftest failures which are encoded as two base64 images and compares them: view-source://people.mozilla.org/~tmielczarek/reftest-analyzer.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML-Unit to compare two XML stings. To get the XML strings you can read the files.

Maven Imports:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit-matchers</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit-assertj3</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

Read in XML-String

```
String xml = new String(
    Files.readAllBytes(xmlFile.toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Check:

```
public void isXmlEqual(String xmlString1, String xmlString2){
        
        Diff diff = DiffBuilder.compare(xmlString1).withTest(xmlString2).ignoreComments().ignoreWhitespace().build();
        Iterator<Difference> differenceIterator = diff.getDifferences().iterator();
        int differenceSize = 0;
        while (differenceIterator.hasNext()) {
            Difference difference = differenceIterator.next();
            log.info( difference.toString() );
            differenceSize++;
        }
        if (differenceSize == 0){
            log.info( "Images are the same" );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sure but the question really seems to be about whether the rendered image looks the same and there are an infinite number of SVG files that have different markup but identical rendering.